# Add Numbers from TextView Android

Tags: android, textview, addition

I need to pick a button, 'H' which represents the atomic element in periodic table, as many times as needed, and it has to add up the overall weight number, and display it in the mw_results.

So far, I am only able to display it, for two times, as I had hard coded it  the value.

Any ideas how I could keep adding the number, without hard coding it..?

Thanks.!

Below is the code:

```
public void Chem()
    {
        final Dialog g = new Dialog(Sol.this);
        g.setContentView(R.layout.table);

        final float[] MoWeight = {0};

        mw_result = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.editText);
        mf_result = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText4);
        Chemname = "";
        final String space = " ";
        final int number = 0;
        Button H = (Button) g.findViewById(R.id.H);
        Button C = (Button) g.findViewById(R.id.C);
        H.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                switch (v.getId()) {

                    case R.id.H:
                        mf_result.append(String.valueOf("H"));
                        mw_result.setText(String.valueOf(123));
                        float MoWeight = Float.valueOf(mw_result.getText().toString());
                        MoWeight = Float.valueOf(mw_result.getText().toString()) + MoWeight;
                        String mw_res=Float.toString(MoWeight);
                        mw_result.setText(mw_res);
                        mw_result = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.editText);
                        g.dismiss();

                }
            }
        });

 C.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                switch (v.getId()) {

                    case R.id.C:
                        mf_result.append(String.valueOf("C"));
                        mw_result.setText(String.valueOf(456));
                        float MoWeight = Float.valueOf(mw_result.getText().toString());
                        MoWeight = Float.valueOf(mw_result.getText().toString()) + MoWeight;
                        String mw_res=Float.toString(MoWeight);
                        mw_result.setText(mw_res);
                        mw_result = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.editText);
                        g.dismiss();
                }
            }
        });
        g.show();
    }
```

Comment: Are you just trying to increase the display by 123 when H is clicked and increase the display by 456 each time C is clicked?

Comment: Yeah this is what I want to happen.

When you Press H the first time you will get the number 123 in the result field. The if you pressed h again it would add onto the current number (123) and give you the number 246 and then if you pressed C while you had the number 246 it would add on 456 giving you 702.
Setting the number 702 to the result field. Hope this is clearer now

Comment: One more question, what exactly are you hoping to achieve with these two lines: `mf_result.append(String.valueOf("H"));
                        mw_result.setText(String.valueOf(123));`

Comment: thanks for the clarification.  I just posted an answer that I think will get you on the right track.  One more thing though, it seems that you're dismissing the dialog on each button click... is that correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you're resetting the text view back to 123 and 456 respectively on each click.

It's kinda hard to see exactly what you want, but this might help you to get on the right track:

```
    public void Chem()
    {
        final Dialog g = new Dialog(Sol.this);
        g.setContentView(R.layout.table);

        final float[] MoWeightArray = {0};  //rename this for readability -- is this used at all?

        mw_result = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.editText);
        mf_result = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText4);
        Chemname = "";
        final String space = " ";
        final int number = 0;
        Button H = (Button) g.findViewById(R.id.H);
        Button C = (Button) g.findViewById(R.id.C);
        H.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                switch (v.getId()) {

                    case R.id.H:
                      String sMW= mw_result.getText().toString();
                      mf_result.append(String.valueOf("H"));  
                      if (sMW.matches("")) { 
                        mw_result.setText(String.valueOf(123));
                      }
                      else{
                        float MoWeight = Float.valueOf(sMW);
                        MoWeight += 123;
                        String mw_res=Float.toString(MoWeight);
                        mw_result.setText(mw_res);
                        //mw_result = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.editText); no need for this 
                        g.dismiss();
                      }

                }
            }
        });

 C.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                switch (v.getId()) {

                    case R.id.C:
                      String sMW= mw_result.getText().toString();
                      mf_result.append(String.valueOf("C"));
                      if (sMW.matches("")) {
                        mw_result.setText(String.valueOf(456));
                      }
                      else{ 
                        float MoWeight = Float.valueOf(sMW);
                        MoWeight += 456;
                        String mw_res=Float.toString(MoWeight);
                        mw_result.setText(mw_res);
                        //mw_result = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.editText); No need for this
                        g.dismiss();
                      }
                }
            }
        });
        g.show();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    public void Chem()
    {
    final Dialog g = new Dialog(Sol.this);
    g.setContentView(R.layout.table);

    final float[] MoWeight = {0};

    mw_result = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.editText);
    mf_result = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText4);
    Chemname = "";
    final String space = " ";
    final int number = 0;

    Button H = (Button) g.findViewById(R.id.H);
    Button C = (Button) g.findViewById(R.id.C);

    mw_result.setTag(1);//1 in case you're updating 123 values 
    mw_result.setTag(2);//2 in case you're updating 456 values 

    H.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int key = Integer.parseInt(mw_result.getTag().toString());
            if(key==2){
                mw_result.setTag(1);//1 in case you're updating 123 values 
                mf_result.append(String.valueOf("H"));
                mw_result.setText(String.valueOf(123));                    
                g.dismiss();
            }
            else{
                float MoWeight = Float.valueOf(mw_result.getText().toString());
                MoWeight = Float.valueOf(mw_result.getText().toString()) + 1;
                String mw_res=Float.toString(MoWeight);
                mw_result.setText(mw_res);
            }
        }
    });

    C.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            int key = Integer.parseInt(mw_result.getTag().toString());
            if(key==1){
                mw_result.setTag(2);//1 in case you're updating 123 values 
                mf_result.append(String.valueOf("C"));
                mw_result.setText(String.valueOf(456));                 
                g.dismiss();
            }
            else{
                float MoWeight = Float.valueOf(mw_result.getText().toString());
                MoWeight = Float.valueOf(mw_result.getText().toString()) + 1;
                String mw_res=Float.toString(MoWeight);
                mw_result.setText(mw_res);
            }
        }
    });
    g.show();
}
```